Self-lighting propane torch in cold weather
I’m looking for easy ways to light camp fires (car camping) in cold weather down to -30 deg C.
Matches seem to work well, pocket lighters only work if warmed up in hands or in a pocket: Minimum temperature for pocket lighters.
What is the minimum temperature a self-lighting torch will ignite at? Such as the Bernzomatic TS4000. I asked the manufacturer, but I haven’t heard back yet.

I originally posted this question to DIY SE, but it was voted to be closed. https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/312020/self-lighting-propane-torch-in-cold-weather?noredirect=1#comment664050_312020

See here for general cold-weather fire starting tips - one good suggestion from that is firesteel/magnesium scraper rods. They work in basically all weather once you get the knack.

If you are car camping, can you plug sth into the 12v power point (formerly known as a cigarette lighter)? In fact can you use an actual car cigarette lighter to ignite your tinder and kindling? But if you are camping what do you have against matches anyway? Camping is (should be) a quite lo-tech activity, and self-igniting matches are a 19th-century invention. Are you car-camping to save money on accomodation, or to leave all those modern trappings behind?

Recent automotive 12V ‘cigarette plugs’ will not tolerate the heat of an actual 12V old fashioned cigarette lighter. They are mostly plastic now, not metal.

The flash point of a flammable liquid is the lowest temperature at which it can release enough vapor to ignite when mixed with air and an adequate external heat source.
The flash point of propane is -156°F (-104°C)
The flash point of MAP-Pro is -162°F (-108°C)
Note: "MAPP" gas was a trademarked fuel originally created by Union Carbide (now defunct). The MAP/MAPP/MAAP fuels available now have various mixtures of chemicals with different flash points.
Note: the vapor pressure of a liquid is proportional to temperature, so the design of any given torch (or pocket lighter if your talking about butane) would possibly be a limiting factor regardless of flash point, as the torch might need a certain vapor pressure to function. Follow torch manufacturers' advice to be certain.

Here’s what Benzomatic said by email:

The TS4000 torch is designed to ignite at temperatures as low as -40°F (-40°C), provided that the fuel (propane or MAP-Pro) is functioning properly under those conditions.


"propane or MAP-Pro" which they also sell, so they really should have commented on how those fuels would function in such cold. If they have (or you've asked them as follow up question), adding their answer here would be useful. :)

@JoryGeerts I asked a follow-up question just now: Regarding, "...provided that the fuel (propane or MAP-Pro) is functioning properly under those conditions." Bernzomatic sells propane and MAP-Pro canisters. Can you comment on how those fuels would function in cold temperatures? Do they function properly under those conditions?
